# Trying to toggle class on group of items for accordion style functionality but it's acting funny

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I am trying to toggle a class on the wrapper of a header (that you click to drop the body) and the body. The class changes the visibility, opacity, and max-height of the body to create the drop down effect.

This first item is dropped down by default. When another is open, all currently open items should close.

instead, when I click on a closed one it opens all of them but and closes the first one that is open by default.

here is my code:

```js
$(".template_wrap").first().addClass("open");

$('.templates').find('.template_header').click(function(){
    $(this).drop();
    $('.template_header').not($(this)).drop();
});

$.fn.drop = function() {
    $(this).parent(".template_wrap").toggleClass('open');
};
```

```css
.page_center {
 margin: 0 auto;
 float: none;
}

.page_center.large {
 width: 95%;
}

.page_center.medium {
 width: 85%;
 max-width: 1350px;
}

.page_center.small {
 width: 85%;
 max-width: 1130px;
}

.page_center.x-small {
 width: 75%;
 max-width: 680px;
}

.page_center:after {
 visibility: hidden;
 display: block;
 content: "";
 clear: both;
 height: 0;
 }
* html .page_center             { zoom: 1; } /* IE6 */
*:first-child+html .page_center { zoom: 1; } /* IE7 */


.template_wrap {
 border: 1px solid #a32021;
 width: 100%;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.template_header {
 background: #a32021;
 position: relative;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 1px 0 1px 2%;
}

.template_header:after {
 position: absolute;
 right: 2%;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 36px;
 font-family:"FontAwesome";
 content: "\f107";
 transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.template_wrap.open .template_header:after {
 -ms-transform: rotate(180deg); 
 -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); 
 transform: rotate(180deg);
 transition: all 0.4s ease;
 content: "\f106";
 top: 30%;
}

.template_header h2 {
 color: #fff;
 margin: 0;
 line-height: 65px;
 font-weight: 400;
}

.template_body {
 
 visibility: hidden;
 opacity: 0;
 max-height: 0;
 transition: opacity .4s ease-out, visibility .4s, max-height: .8s;
}

.template_wrap.open .template_body {
 visibility: visible;
 opacity: 1;
 max-height: 10000px;
 transition: opacity .4s ease-out, visibility .4s, max-height: .8s;
 padding: 2%;
}

.template_links {
 width: 50%;
 float: left;
}

.template_links_wrap {
 border: 1px solid #f47628;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 list-style: none;
}

.template_links_wrap li {
 padding-left: 3%;
 line-height: 52px;
}

.template_links_wrap li:nth-child(odd) {
 background: #fbe4d6;
}

.template_links_wrap li a {
 color: #f47628;
}

.template_img {
 width: 50%; 
 float: right;
}

.template_img img {
 margin: 0 auto;
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class="content templates">
  <div class="page_center medium">
   
   <div class="template_wrap">
    <div class="template_header">
     <h2>Template Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="template_body">
     <div class="page_center">
      <div class="template_links">
       <ul class="template_links_wrap">
        <li><a href="#">Download PDF</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Download PDF</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Download PDF</a></li>
       </ul> 
      </div>
      <div class="template_img">
       <img src="images/template_placeholder.jpg">
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="template_wrap">
    <div class="template_header">
     <h2>Template Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="template_body">
     <div class="page_center">
      <div class="template_links">
       <ul class="template_links_wrap">
        <li><a href="#">Download PDF</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Download PDF</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Download PDF</a></li>
       </ul> 
      </div>
      <div class="template_img">
       <img src="images/template_placeholder.jpg">
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="template_wrap">
    <div class="template_header">
     <h2>Template Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="template_body">
     <div class="page_center">
      <div class="template_links">
       <ul class="template_links_wrap">
        <li><a href="#">Download PDF</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Download PDF</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Download PDF</a></li>
       </ul> 
      </div>
      <div class="template_img">
       <img src="images/template_placeholder.jpg">
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

  </div>
 </section>
```

Also, Something strange happens to the h2s where they move around based on various clicks. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
$(".template_wrap").first().addClass("open");

$('.template_header').click(function(){
  $('.template_wrap').removeClass("open");
  $(this).parent().addClass("open");
})
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/26kasg4t/

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is to make all accordions close and then afterwards make `this` the only one open:

```
$('.template_wrap:first').addClass('open');

$('.template_header').click(function() {
  if ($(this).parent().hasClass('open')) {
    $('.template_wrap').removeClass('open');
    $('.template_body').slideUp();
  } else {
    $('.template_wrap').removeClass('open');
    $('.template_body').slideUp();
    $(this).next('.template_body').slideDown();
    $(this).parent().addClass('open');
  }
});
```

Added a condition, should an accordion be open while it's clicked, it will just close.

#### SNIPPET

```js
$('.template_wrap:first').addClass('open');

$('.template_header').click(function() {
  if ($(this).parent().hasClass('open')) {
    $('.template_wrap').removeClass('open');
    $('.template_body').slideUp();
  } else {
    $('.template_wrap').removeClass('open');
    $('.template_body').slideUp();
    $(this).next('.template_body').slideDown();
    $(this).parent().addClass('open');
  }
});
```

```css
.page_center {
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: none;
}
.page_center.large {
  width: 95%;
}
.page_center.medium {
  width: 85%;
  max-width: 1350px;
}
.page_center.small {
  width: 85%;
  max-width: 1130px;
}
.page_center.x-small {
  width: 75%;
  max-width: 680px;
}
.page_center:after {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
}
* html .page_center {
  zoom: 1;
}
/* IE6 */

*:first-child+html .page_center {
  zoom: 1;
}
/* IE7 */

.template_wrap {
  border: 1px solid #a32021;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.template_header {
  background: #a32021;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 1px 0 1px 2%;
}
.template_header:after {
  position: absolute;
  right: 2%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  content: "\f107";
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
.template_wrap.open .template_header:after {
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  content: "\f106";
  top: 30%;
}
.template_header h2 {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 65px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.template_body {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: opacity .4s ease-out, visibility .4s, max-height: .8s;
}
.template_wrap.open .template_body {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  max-height: 10000px;
  transition: opacity .4s ease-out, visibility .4s, max-height: .8s;
  padding: 2%;
}
.template_links {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
.template_links_wrap {
  border: 1px solid #f47628;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.template_links_wrap li {
  padding-left: 3%;
  line-height: 52px;
}
.template_links_wrap li:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #fbe4d6;
}
.template_links_wrap li a {
  color: #f47628;
}
.template_img {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
}
.template_img img {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class="content templates">
  <div class="page_center medium">

    <div class="template_wrap">
      <div class="template_header">
        <h2>Template Header</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="template_body">
        <div class="page_center">
          <div class="template_links">
            <ul class="template_links_wrap">
              <li><a href="#">Download PDF</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Download PDF</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Download PDF</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="template_img">
            <img src="images/template_placeholder.jpg">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="template_wrap">
      <div class="template_header">
        <h2>Template Header</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="template_body">
        <div class="page_center">
          <div class="template_links">
            <ul class="template_links_wrap">
              <li><a href="#">Download PDF</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Download PDF</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Download PDF</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="template_img">
            <img src="images/template_placeholder.jpg">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="template_wrap">
      <div class="template_header">
        <h2>Template Header</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="template_body">
        <div class="page_center">
          <div class="template_links">
            <ul class="template_links_wrap">
              <li><a href="#">Download PDF</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Download PDF</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Download PDF</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="template_img">
            <img src="images/template_placeholder.jpg">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```